# How to get Python Scrapy Crawler details?

Tags: php, python, scrapy

I am using the Python Scrapy tool to extract data from websites. I'm firing Scrapy from my php code using `proc_open()`. Now I need to maintain a Dashboard kind of thing. Is there a way in Scrapy to get Crawler details like:

1. Time taken by Crawler to run.
2. Start and Stop Time of crawler.
3. Crawler Status (active or stopped).
4. List of Crawlers running simultaneously.

Comment: You can write your own extension to store the any data you want to display in your dashboard. Then read in your app without interacting directly with scrapy. Do you need a more detailed answer?

Comment: @Rho. Yes a more detailed answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Rho.. I am waiting for your detailed answer.. I t will be very helpful if you provide some more input on this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by using an extension.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

from scrapy import signals
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall


class SpiderDetails(object):
    """Extension for collect spider information like start/stop time."""

    update_interval = 5  # in seconds

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        # keep a reference to the crawler in case is needed to access to more information
        self.crawler = crawler
        # keep track of polling calls per spider
        self.pollers = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        instance = cls(crawler)
        crawler.signals.connect(instance.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(instance.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return instance

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        # store curent timestamp in db as 'start time' for this spider
        # TODO: complete db calls

        # start activity poller
        poller = self.pollers[spider.name] = LoopingCall(self.spider_update, spider)
        poller.start(self.update_interval)

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        # store curent timestamp in db as 'end time' for this spider
        # TODO: complete db calls

        # remove and stop activity poller
        poller = self.pollers.pop(spider.name)
        poller.stop()

    def spider_update(self, spider):
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        # update 'last update time' for this spider
        # TODO: complete db calls
        pass
```

1. **Time taken by Crawler to run**: that is `end time - start time`. You can calculate it when reading from db or storing as well with the end time.
2. **Start and Stop Time of crawler**: that is stored in `spider_opened` and `spider_closed` methods.
3. **Crawler Status (Active or Stopped)**: your crawler is active if `now - last update time` is close to 5 seconds. Otherwise, if the last update was a long time ago (30 secs, 5 minutes or more), then your spider has either stopped abnormally or hanged up. If the spider record has an `end time` then the crawler has finished correctly.
4. **List of Crawlers running simultaneously**: your frontend can query for the records with an empty `end time`. Those spiders will be either running or dead (in case the `last update time` was a long time ago).

Take in consideration that the `spider_closed` signal will not be called in case the process finish abruptly. You will need to have a cron job to cleanup and/or update the dead records.

Don't forget to add the extension to your `settings.py` file, like:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    # SpiderDetails class is in the file mybot/extensions.py
    'mybot.extensions.SpiderDetails': 1000,
}
```

Comment: @Rho.. Thanks for the detailed info on developing an Extension.. I will follow the info and let you know on my progress.. Thanks..